# White flash/blink on hover with Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, hover

I have a rather strange problem on a site I designed. Every time you hover in or out of a link, the link element and in some cases its parent flashes white quickly. This happens on every link, not just the ones with transition effect or different hover color. On FF, everything works just fine. Also the white is not the bgcolor of body.

What makes it even more mysterious is that I haven't done any changes to the site. I only updated Chrome..

I would post an image too but as I am a new user I'm not allowed to, gotta do it as a link:
http://www.planetoidi.com/temp/hover.jpg

Comment: please share your code for better understanding

Comment: I don't know which part of the code to paste here.. the problem appears across all pages and I noticed just now that even when I select and deselect text, it also blinks white. In any case, here's the basic code for a element:  

     `a{  
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;  
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;  
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;  
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;   
    transition: all 0.3s ease;  
    
}  


a, a:visited{  
    color: $link;  
    text-decoration: none;  
}`

Sorry for the terrible formatting, I'm trying to find line break :)

Comment: I also checked out some of the previous sites I've made and some are displaying the same symptoms (they never did before). Then again some sites are working fine so I guess I need to find out what they have incommon.

Comment: can your create an example here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: This was just some glitch, fixed by rebooting. Weird one tho.. I will answer and close this as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a large class of bugs in Chrome which show a flash (white or black, depending on the bug) when transitioning to or from accelerated rendering. This can happen on hover when there is a CSS transition from the non-hover state.

A workaround is to ensure that the base state of the element is using accelerated rendering. One way is to add the following rule for your element (without the :hover selector):

`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`

Source: http://www.sitepoint.com/fix-chrome-animation-flash-bug/